# How can I get mailboxes settings from iPad to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, email

I have long settings in iPad and I would like to get them automatically to devices such as iPhone and poussible to Mac in the future. How can I get the settings over all devices?

Comment: Mail settings are stored in iOS backups.  Most just load a backup and then make incremental changes as new changes arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was that maybe you could use iTunes to sync your Mail settings back to your Mac. Then I found this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1296

> Mail account settings (email address, display name, server name, and user name) are synced from the computer to the iOS device; ***iTunes does not sync settings from the iOS device back to the computer*** and does not sync any email messages.

So considering this, I think your best option is to configure your complex Mail Settings on your Mac by hand first. Then, you could use iTunes to automatically sync those settings to all your iOS devices. Not a 100% solution for your problem, but I think it's the best you can do within the limitations you have.

Comment: +1 meaning I need to buy a cheap mac, not that bad option, things work pretty well between different Apple -devices. Yet, still interested whether I could get the settings from iPad to MBA and iPhone -- without redoing everything in MBA.